# How to get Pandas dataframe to work with numpy and scipy user-defined function?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

Any help would be appreciated, as I am running into an error when using Pandas with the below function.

Here is an example setup I am trying to use:

```
example_data = {'age': [37,37,27,22,32,22,42,32,37,22], 'target': [0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0]}
example_df = pd.DataFrame(data=example_data)
example_df
```

I have called the rdc function as follows:

```
ldc(x=example_data['age'],y=example_data['target'])
```

However, I am running into an issue:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-248-c4a80b9f6e55> in <module>()
----> 1 ldc(x=example_data['age'],y=example_data['target'])

<ipython-input-231-78a770305f24> in ldc(x, y, f, k, s, n)
     29         return np.median(values)
     30 
---> 31     if len(x.shape) == 1: x = x.values.reshape((-1, 1))
     32     if len(y.shape) == 1: y = y.values.reshape((-1, 1))
     33 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Below is the function itself that I am using:

```
"""
Implements the Randomized Dependence Coefficient
David Lopez-Paz, Philipp Hennig, Bernhard Schoelkopf
http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5138-the-randomized-dependence-coefficient.pdf
"""
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rankdata

def rdc(x, y, f=np.sin, k=20, s=1/6., n=1):
    """
    Computes the Randomized Dependence Coefficient
    x,y: numpy arrays 1-D or 2-D
         If 1-D, size (samples,)
         If 2-D, size (samples, variables)
    f:   function to use for random projection
    k:   number of random projections to use
    s:   scale parameter
    n:   number of times to compute the RDC and
         return the median (for stability)
    According to the paper, the coefficient should be relatively insensitive to
    the settings of the f, k, and s parameters.
    """
    if n > 1:
        values = []
        for i in range(n):
            try:
                values.append(rdc(x, y, f, k, s, 1))
            except np.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: pass
        return np.median(values)

    if len(x.shape) == 1: x = x.values.reshape((-1, 1))
    if len(y.shape) == 1: y = y.values.reshape((-1, 1))

    # Copula Transformation
    cx = np.column_stack([rankdata(xc, method='ordinal') for xc in x.T])/float(x.size)
    cy = np.column_stack([rankdata(yc, method='ordinal') for yc in y.T])/float(y.size)

    # Add a vector of ones so that w.x + b is just a dot product
    O = np.ones(cx.shape[0])
    X = np.column_stack([cx, O])
    Y = np.column_stack([cy, O])

    # Random linear projections
    Rx = (s/X.shape[1])*np.random.randn(X.shape[1], k)
    Ry = (s/Y.shape[1])*np.random.randn(Y.shape[1], k)
    X = np.dot(X, Rx)
    Y = np.dot(Y, Ry)

    # Apply non-linear function to random projections
    fX = f(X)
    fY = f(Y)

    # Compute full covariance matrix
    C = np.cov(np.hstack([fX, fY]).T)

    # Due to numerical issues, if k is too large,
    # then rank(fX) < k or rank(fY) < k, so we need
    # to find the largest k such that the eigenvalues
    # (canonical correlations) are real-valued
    k0 = k
    lb = 1
    ub = k
    while True:

        # Compute canonical correlations
        Cxx = C[:k, :k]
        Cyy = C[k0:k0+k, k0:k0+k]
        Cxy = C[:k, k0:k0+k]
        Cyx = C[k0:k0+k, :k]

        eigs = np.linalg.eigvals(np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(Cxx), Cxy),
                                        np.dot(np.linalg.inv(Cyy), Cyx)))

        # Binary search if k is too large
        if not (np.all(np.isreal(eigs)) and
                0 <= np.min(eigs) and
                np.max(eigs) <= 1):
            ub -= 1
            k = (ub + lb) / 2
            continue
        if lb == ub: break
        lb = k
        if ub == lb + 1:
            k = ub
        else:
            k = (ub + lb) / 2

    return np.sqrt(np.max(eigs))
```

Comment: You call your dictionary (which has a list as value), instead of your data frame, where it is a series

Comment: As @Jondiedoop said, you probably want `ldc(x=example_df['age'], y=example_df['target'])`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I receive the following error:

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

When using the suggested:

ldc(x=example_df['age'], y=example_df['target'])

Answer (score 0):

You mistakenly  passed `example_data` instead of `example_df` on the following line.

```
ldc(x=example_data['age'],y=example_data['target'])
```

rename the variable as follows.

```
ldc(x=example_df['age'],y=example_df['target'])
```